# Importing a mode dynamically using a variable

Tags: python

I have about 580 tables and would like to  import them using a variable if possible. Say the variable is `current_product`. Say for example the `current_product = "apples"` how can i get:

```
from app.models import #####
```

to import the the apple table please?
I apologize in advance if the question is not complex enough for some.

Comment: `from app import models; getattr(models, current_product)`

Comment: hey, thank you @deceze. I get the following: getattr(models, PG_ticker)
Out[34]: app.models.apples. how do I go from there please ?

Comment: ‍♂️ `the_product = getattr(models, current_product)` — Then do whatever you plan on doing with `the_product`…

Comment: Sorry to bother, I usually call table with  pd.DataFrame.from_records(TotalSales.objects.all().values()). I do not know how to proceed when using getattr. Could you help ?

Comment: You want to emulate `from app.models import apples`, where `apples` is dynamic and based on a variable, right? So: `apples = getattr(models, 'apples')`. There. Now you're at the same point as if you just hardcoded `from app.models import apples`. Whatever you want to do with `apples` I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, thank you. this works for me: pd.DataFrame.from_records(current_product.objects.all().values())